# Spring mvc autowire RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to autowire `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping` in my spring mvc controller in order to get all url mappings and display them on UI, but not successfull. There is error that the bean is missing:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could    not autowire field: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping web.controller.WorkController.handlerMapping; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My web.xml:

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="web.controller"/>
             <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My root-context.xml:

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="web.beans.HelloBean"/>
```

The java controller:

```
package web.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;
import web.beans.HelloBean;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class WorkController {

    @Autowired RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;
    @Autowired private HelloBean helloBean;
    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should initiate the RequestMappingHandlerMapping bean  before autowired it.
It has two way:

1. In springxml config such as hello bean

> ```
> <bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
> <!-- add your properties here property name="..." value="..."></property-->
> </bean>
> ```

2. Or using

   @Configuration

   ```
   @Configuration 
   @ComponentScan("your.package") 
   @EnableWebMvc   
   public class AppConfig {  
   ...
       @Bean
       public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
          RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
          // add properties here
          return mapping;
       }
   ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Try to get all request `urls`, The code below may be useful for you.

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
Map<String, HandlerMapping> allRequestMappings = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(appContext, HandlerMapping.class, true, false);
for (HandlerMapping handlerMapping : allRequestMappings.values()) {
    if (handlerMapping instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
          RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = (RequestMappingHandlerMapping) handlerMapping;
          Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();
          for (Map.Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> requestMappingInfoHandlerMethodEntry : handlerMethods.entrySet()) {
             RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo = requestMappingInfoHandlerMethodEntry.getKey();
             PatternsRequestCondition patternsCondition = requestMappingInfo.getPatternsCondition();
             String requestUrl = SetUtils.first(patternsCondition.getPatterns());
             System.out.println(requestUrl);
          }
    }
}
```

Frankly speaking, `java reflect` is a key point to get all request `urls`. if you look into the spring-mvc source deeply, you will find the `implementation classes` of  `HandlerMapping` interface, such as

```
AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping, AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping,
AbstractHandlerMapping, AbstractHandlerMethodMapping,
AbstractUrlHandlerMapping, BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping, 
ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping, ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping,
DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping, RequestMappingHandlerMapping,
RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping, SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
```

Comment: What is SetUtils.first()?

Comment: @NickJ think of it as

`final Set<String> patterns = patternsCondition.getPatterns();
String requestUrl = patterns.stream().findFirst().orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY);`

Answer (score 2):

- i try to add "**@EnableWebFlux**" in my Main class and it works(in my
  situation).
- so i think maybe "**EnableWebMvc**" works so..
- it works fine for me, don`t ↓ me please  :)

```java
@EnableWebFlux(for webflux)
@EnableWebMvc(for commvc)
@SpringBootApplication
public class InstoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(InstoreApplication.class)......
    }
}
```

Comment: ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-enable

Answer (score 0):

You can add these in *.properties file:

```
# Log restful end points
logging.level.web=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE
```